# How to use SDL with OGRE?

Tags: c++, sdl, ogre3d

When I go to use [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) with [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) (as described in [this article](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/Using_SDL_Input)), I seem to be having trouble with a second window that appears behind my main render window.  Basically, the code I'm using is this:

```
SDL_init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, SDL_OPENGL);

Ogre::Root *root = new Ogre::Root();
root->restoreConfig();
root->initialise(false);

Ogre::NameValuePairList windowSettings;
windowSettings["currentGLContext"] = Ogre::String("True");
Ogre::RenderWindow *window = root->createRenderWindow("MainRenderWindow", 640, 480, false, &windowSettings);
window->setVisible(true);
```

The question is, how do I get rid of the extra window?

Just for posterity, I'm using OGRE 1.6.4, Mac OS X 10.6.2, and SDL 1.2.14.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out on my own.  The problem ends up being that OGRE's Mac GL backend does not honor the `currentGLContext` option, so the best solution is to change to SDL 1.3 (directly from Subversion, as of time of writing) and use the `SDL_CreateWindowFrom` call to start getting events from a window created by OGRE.  It should also be noted that the OGRE window needs to have the `macAPI` set to `cocoa`, or else SDL won't recognize the window handle.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you already solved your problem, but not all users will be content with downgrading SDL to 1.3. You can use SDL2 and an SDL2 window created via SDL_CreateWindow with OGRE. The code would look something like this:

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
    OGRE_EXCEPT(Ogre::Exception::ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR, "Cannot initialize SDL2!",
        "BaseApplication::setup");
}

Ogre::Root *root = new Ogre::Root();
root->restoreConfig();
root->initialise(false);

Ogre::NameValuePairList params; // ogre window / render system params
SDL_Window *sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("myWindow", posX, posY, width, height, vflags);
// see SDL_CreateWindow docs / examples for how to populate posX, posY, width, height, and vflags according to your needs

SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
if (SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(sdlWindow, &wmInfo) == SDL_FALSE) {
    OGRE_EXCEPT(Ogre::Exception::ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR,
        "Couldn't get WM Info! (SDL2)",
        "BaseApplication::setup");
}

params.insert(std::make_pair("macAPI", "cocoa"));
params.insert(std::make_pair("macAPICocoaUseNSView", "true"));

// grab a string representing the NSWindow pointer
Ogre::String winHandle = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)wmInfo.info.cocoa.window);

// assign the NSWindow pointer to the parentWindowHandle parameter
params.insert(std::make_pair("parentWindowHandle", winHandle));

Ogre::RenderWindow *ogreWindow = root->createRenderWindow("myWindowTitle", width, height, isFullscreen, &params);
// see OGRE documentation on how to populate width, height, and isFullscreen to suit your needs

// create OGRE scene manager, camera, viewports, etc
```