# How do I collect input from an external window using SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl, ogre3d

I'm currently trying to re-write my binder between Ogre and SDL in my game engine.  Originally I used the method outlined in the Ogre Wiki [here.](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Using+SDL+Input#New_Experimental_Way_OGRE_v1.6_and_Later_)  I recently updated my version of SDL to 1.3 and noticed the "SDL_CreateWindowFrom()" function call and re-implemented my binder to allow Ogre to build the window, and then get the HWND from Ogre to be passed into SDL.

Only one window is made and I see everything renders properly, however no input is collected.  I have no idea why.  Here's the code I am currently working with (on windows):

```
OgreWindow = Ogre::Root::getSingleton().createRenderWindow(WindowCaption, Settings.RenderWidth, Settings.RenderHeight, Settings.Fullscreen, &Opts);
size_t Data = 0;
OgreWindow->getCustomAttribute("WINDOW",&Data);
SDLWindow = SDL_CreateWindowFrom(&Data);
SDL_SetWindowGrab(SDLWindow,SDL_TRUE);
```

I've tried looking around and there are a number of people that have done this to one degree of success or another(such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978883/how-to-use-sdl-with-ogre) or [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=53359#p401129)).  But no one seems to comment on handling the input after implementing this.

I originally thought that maybe since SDL does not own the window it wouldn't collect input from it by default, which is reasonable.  So I searched the SDL API and only found that one function "SDL_SetWindowGrab()" that seems to relate to input capture.  But calling that has no effect.

How can I get SDL to collect input from my Ogre-made window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been a while, but I figured I would put in the answer for others that may need it.  It turned out to be a bug/incomplete feature in SDL 1.3.  The "CreateWindowFrom" method wasn't originally intended to be used exclusively as an input handler.  At the time of this writing I know myself and another on my team wrote patches for Windows and Linux that permitted this use to work and submitted those patches to SDL.